# Format Date in AppScript - Google Sheets to Google Doc conversion

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google Sheet that collects Google Form responses. Two of the questions collect dates. I'm running a script that collects the information from the form responses sheet and generates a Google Doc. I've formatted the date various ways, but when it gets pulled into the Google Doc, it reverts back to **Tue Apr 27 2021 05:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)**. I want it just to say 'Month Day, Year' when pulled into the Google Doc.

I've been able to format the cells with the dates using, but this formatting is only reflected in the Google Sheet:

```
datasheet.getRange(row + 1, 14).setNumberFormat("mmmm d, yyyy")
```

I've attempted creating a variable containing the date and passing it through formateDate(), but I get an error saying:
**Exception: The parameters (number[], String, String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.**

```
var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone()
var arrivalDate = datasheet.getRange(row + 1, 13).getValues()
var formatedArrivalDate = Utilities.formatDate(arrivalDate, timeZone, 'mmmm d, yyyy')
datasheet.getRange(row + 1, 13).setValue(formattedArrivalDate)
```

And the correct parameters for Utilities.formateDate() are: Date, String, String

The 'merge' portion of the code reads:

```
for (var col = 3; col < 100; ++col) {
    body.replace('{_' + data[0][col] + '_}', data[row][col]
}
```

(The data is defined previously and is not where my issue lies.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are providing a two-dimensional array as the first parameter in [formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format); you should provide a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instead.

#### Explanation and solution:

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a 2D array. If you want to retrieve the value of a single cell, you should use [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) instead:

```
var arrivalDate = datasheet.getRange(row + 1, 13).getValue();
```

#### Other issue:

In [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `Month` is identified by capital `M`, not `m` (which refers to minutes).

Therefore, you should format the date like this instead:

```
var formatedArrivalDate = Utilities.formatDate(arrivalDate, timeZone, 'MMMM d, yyyy')
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the issue of not being able to pass it as a parameter. But now it returns any date with '0000' for the month, but the remainder of the date matches the day and year. I've changed the month formatting to various other formats, but still I get '0' for however many 'm' I put for the month. Any thoughts?

Comment: @lmoreno21 The `m` should be capitalized. Please check my updated answer.